# How can I solve these edges to disappear?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, edges, windows

I am working on a window frame and I had to add some loop cut and mirror modif. to finish it, but there are some edges what I cannot solve with limited dissolve. [image]

Comment: Are they actually causing any problem? You can problably leave them in place unless they're causing issues with textures. You can share your file (with just the window frame if it's a very large file) via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there if you wish so that we can have a look.

Comment: I will check out the textures then, if it look oké, then I will accept it. It just bothering my eyes haha. Thank you

Comment: ...but not _all_ of those edges are necessary, to surround valid faces. So you're right to have a think. The surplus edges might indicate problems with the mesh. Jiggle a few vertices around, hide a few adjacent faces, and have a look for internal faces, open edges, double vertices.